# Include a static html image in a dynamic database loading code

Tags: php, html, prestashop, smarty

I have the below code which will load product pictures in the product page's long description in Prestashop, it works great to load all the product images below each other，I would like to add a little "logo" separator after every two images， below an example image

```
{foreach from=$product.images item=image}
     <li>
        <img
          src="{$image.bySize.thickbox_default.url}"
          alt="{$image.legend}"
          title="{$image.legend}"
          width="100%"
          itemprop="image"
        >
      </li>
    {/foreach}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just count the number of images displayed' while adding the logo every 2 images? (If (countImages % 2 == 0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add a logo after each product image by adding `if` condition within the loop as you can see below:

```
{foreach from=$product.images item=image name=product_image}
    <li>
        <img
            src="{$image.bySize.thickbox_default.url}"
            alt="{$image.legend}"
            title="{$image.legend}"
            width="100%"
            itemprop="image"
        >
      </li>

      {if $smarty.foreach.product_image.index % 2 === 1}
          <img class="logo" src="/img/logo-separator.png" />
      {/if}
{/foreach}
```

First of all, just add `name=product_image` on `foreach` loop of product images to get the indices of each image by using `smarty` then check the index of `foreach` items and after every second image just add a logo by `$smarty.foreach.product_image.index % 2 === 1`